# Adding OpenID support in broadleaf commerce

Tags: spring-security, openid, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to add OpenID support to broadleaf commerce application.
I was able to work out a working standalone web application using Spring OpenID.

In my site/pom.xml of my broadleaf commerce app, I added this :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Doing Maven build after this resulted in compilation error at 'produces' attribute of @RequestMapping wherever it is used in application.

"**The attribute produces is undefined for the annotation type RequestMapping**"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", produces = "text/html")
public String add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model,
```

The build path of project does shows spring-web.3.0.7.RELEASE jar.

Project refresh/clean also didn't help.

I am using Broadleaf 2.0.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start off by identifying myself as an employee of Broadleaf Commerce.

I don't believe the "produces" attribute was introduced until Spring-Web 3.1. I reviewed the pom.xml for Broadleaf core for version 2.0 and we specify a dependency on spring-web and spring-webmvc 3.1.3.RELEASE. I also confirmed that during a default build of the Broadleaf DemoSite for 2.0 that the 3.1.3.RELEASE versions are produced in WEB-INF/lib (and no other versions). This makes me think that one or more additional libraries you have declared a dependency on in your own project have a transitive dependency on an earlier version of spring-web. You may need to include an "exclusions" element in your dependency declaration to remove the offending dependency.

Comment: Adding exclusions also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple adding exclusions didn't helped as it removed all the exluded dependencies irrespective of their version. (The exclusion tag does not allow you to specify version to be excluded.

I had to add the exluded dependencies with correct version as follow:-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```